# Constructor that will take any type of function as a parameter

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Purpose of Code:** I need to be able to feed in any function type as a parameter to a constructor so that I may call it from inside that class.

**Why does it have to be this way?** Because I'm using **Unreal Engine 4** *FRunnable* threading which is done is such a way that the thread will call specific interfaces (virtual member functions) to run the thread so unless I want to make a new class for every thread task I would like to assign, I have to try and feed it generic functions so that I can have maximum functionality from my Threading class.

**What am I using the threading class for?** *SQLite3* queries, each query that requires data saving always requires different parameters where as my **SELECT** queries.

This is my code below, the first part works fine but the second constructor, does not;

*Threading class constructor*

```
FThreading::FThreading(std::function<void()> funcTask) {

    //Check if the Thread has not been defined and that the system supports multi threading
    if (!Thread && FPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()) {

        //Create our thread
        voidNoParaFunc = funcTask;
        curFlag = 1;
        Thread = FRunnableThread::Create(this, TEXT("FThreading"), 0, TPri_BelowNormal);

    } else {

        //Can't multithread, call the function straight
        funcTask();

    }
}
```

*The call:*

```
std::function<void()> passFunc = std::bind(&UCP_GameInstance::InitDB, GameInst);
FThreading* threadPointer = new FThreading(passFunc);
```

Now this is the code that won't work that I need help with:

```
FThreading::FThreading(std::function<bool(FString, FString)> funcTask) {

    //Check if the Thread has not been defined and that the system supports multi threading
    if (!Thread && FPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()) {

        //Create our thread
        boolTwoString = funcTask();
        curFlag = 2;
        Thread = FRunnableThread::Create(this, TEXT("FThreading"), 0, TPri_BelowNormal);

    }
    else {

        //Can't multithread, call the function straight
        funcTask();

    }
}
```

*The call:*

```
void UCP_GameInstance::AddNewSurvivor(FString First, FString Second, FString Nation, FString Age, FString Blood, FString Level, FString Spec) {

FString Query = "INSERT INTO SurvivorData (First, Second, Nation, Age, Blood, Level, Spec) " +
    "VALUES (" + First + ", " + Second + ", " + Nation + ", " + Age + ", " + Blood + ", " + Level + ", " + Spec + ");";

std::function<bool(FString, FString)> passFunc = std::bind(&USQLiteDatabase::ExecSql, GetDBName(), Query);
FThreading* threadPointer = new FThreading(passFunc);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this issue for a while and now, even design suggestions/changes would be more than invited.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out with the `std::bind`, you can't really pass any random function - how would `FThreading` know how to call it? There is an actual call instruction `funcTask();` which tells us immediately that `funcTask` takes no arguments.

Now, in your second overload, `funcTask` takes two `FString` arguments. Obviously, that means the `funcTask();` call there is nonsense. It's simply missing both arguments. We cannot invent those arguments for you.

This is a general problem with the idea in your title, "take any type of function as a parameter". It generally fails, not because it's impossible to pass any function, but because it's then impossible to call that function.

PS. `boolTwoString = funcTask();` should be just `boolTwoString = funcTask` - it's after all not a direct call there.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Would you know how I could get around this issue? It has been a thorn in my side for a while.

Comment: @NullByte: As I said, we have no idea how your thread is supposed to come up with those two string arguments. Just to check whether you're not making any silly assumptions: `ExecSql` takes 4 string arguments, right? Because you've bound two arguments and apparently have two unbound string arguments left.

Comment: With your advice I've managed to make it work, thank you for your time in helping me, I really appreciate it